# Search for a bracket in an array thats begins with a `+`

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I know how to search for a specific bracket in a array:

```
var arr = ['a','f','+'];

if($.inArray('+', arr) != -1){
   alert("Contains a  single +");
}
```

Now my question is: how can I check if the array contains brackets that begin with a `+`. And, if so, how many `+` contains this bracket.

Comment: What does "how i can check if the array contains brackets that beginn with a +" mean?

Comment: Brackets? Do you mean items? Please be more explicit. What input/output do you have/expect?

Comment: I mean items like `'++'` or `'+++'`. Items that only consist of `+`! Thanks

Comment: [Array filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: `if($.inArray('+', arr) === 0){ ...` would tell if you the first array index contains `'+'`? To check partial matches to strings etc. you'll have to iterate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regular loop and match with a regex of `/^\++$/g`:

```
var arr = ['a','f','+','foo','asd+asd', '+++++++'];

for (var i = 0, arrLength = arr.length, match; i < arrLength; i++) {
    match = arr[i].match(/^\++$/g);

    if (match) {
        console.log(arr[i] + ' contains ' + match[0].length + ' plus sign(s)');
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
+ contains 1 plus sign(s)
+++++++ contains 7 plus sign(s)
```

---

Alternately (since it's a bit hard to understand your question), the following would count how many items in the array were only plusses:

```
var arr = ['a','f','+','foo','asd+asd', '+++++++'];

var onlyPlusses = [];

for (var i = 0, arrLength = arr.length; i < arrLength; i++) {
    if (arr[i].match(/^\++$/g)) {
        onlyPlusses.push(arr[i]);
    }
}

console.log('arr has ' + onlyPlusses.length + ' items that only consist of plusses');
```

Outputs:

```
arr has 2 items that only consist of plusses
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an object to maintain a list of what array indexes hold a plus count.

```
var obj = {};
for (var i  = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
  if (arr[i].indexOf('+') > -1) {
    obj[i] = arr[i].match(/\+/g).length;
  }
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/LTuG2/)

**Example**

```
var arr = ['a', '+', 'd', '+++'] // {1: 1, 3: 3}
```